# How does extending work in LeafletJS and why do I need an intermediary attribution for it to work correctly?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, extend

First of all, this might not be a LeafletJS question, but a mere JS one, but I haven't come across it until Leaflet.

I've been experimenting with Leaflet lately and at some point wanted to pass to a function an extended version of a Control object (for those who also work with Java or similar language, I was trying to do something similar with instantiating an anonymous class).

So:

Given the class L.Control (which I wanted to extend with the method x), I tried:

```
func(new L.Control.extend({x: function() {}})());
```

which fails miserably, because the parameter of the function `func` is undefined.

However:

```
var v = L.Control.extend({x: function() { }}); 
func(new v());
```

works perfectly, as `new v()` returns, as expected, a `L.Control` object with an extra  x function.

Bottom line: what is the difference between the 2 snippets of code and how can I make it work with a one-liner (if possible)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experiments, I figured it out by myself.

The problems is due to the order of operations and the solution was to add a set of brackets, the one-liner becoming:

```
func(new (L.Control.extend({x: function() {}}))());
```

Comment: If you're not going to change one of the classes's methods and only going to add functions to the class you should use the `include` method: `L.Control.include({'x': function () {}});`